# count number of items in np.where() array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I am currently attempting to compare two columns in a pandas DataFrame:

```
--------------- Cluster Assignment ---------------
           ID      Class   Cluster
    0   1000025      2        4
    1   1002945      2        2
    2   1015425      2        4
    3   1016277      2        2
    4   1017023      2        4
    5   1017122      4        2
    6   1018099      2        4
    7   1018561      2        4
    8   1033078      2        4
    9   1033078      2        4
    10  1035283      2        4
    11  1036172      2        4
    12  1041801      4        4
    13  1043999      2        4
    14  1044572      4        2
    15  1047630      4        4
    16  1048672      2        4
    17  1049815      2        4
    18  1050670      4        2
    19  1050718      2        4
```

in an attempt to find the number of rows that don't match to find the ratio of errors in my dataframe (the full df is much longer than this). I'm using `np.where()` to make the comparison, and I'm getting an accurate output of all the rows that are incorrect, but now I want to add how many rows are wrong, then divide that by the total number of rows.. my problem now is that I'm getting:

```
>>> data= np.where(df7['Class']!=df7['Cluster'])
>>> print(len(data))
1
```

if I print the type for dataI get `< class 'tuple' >`. So, I tried converting from tuple to list using:

```
>>> print(list(data))
[array([  9,  11,  17,  31,  32,  33,  34,  36,  38,  62,  64,  65, 135,
   156, 196, 201, 277, 301], dtype=int64)]
```

Obviously, this isn't helpful because if I try to print/store the length of that list, I get

```
>>> print(list(data))
[array([  9,  29,  30,  31,  33,  35,  59,  61,  62, 132, 153, 193, 198,
   274, 298], dtype=int64)]
>>> print('errors: ', len(cluster2wrong))
errors:  1
```

Could someone point me in the direction of how I can just count these items?

Comment: have you tried using `print(len(data[0]))` on your first example ?

Comment: `data` is a tuple, one item per dimension of the array.  `data[0]` is an array, the indicies for one of those dimensions.

Comment: what does the structure of `data` actually look like? Converting it to something else just to count the number of elements you're interested in seems pointless, you can just query the size of the the thing you get back. Or whatever sub-part of it you're actually after.

Comment: @hpaulj just grabbing len(data[0]) got me the information I was looking for. I was able to divide that by the length of the original df I was pulling from, and get my error rate. Now the problem is that half the time I run it, I get a 4% error rate, and the other half i get a 95% error rate.. No idea why that's happening, but that is for another question, I suppose! Thanks!

Comment: @pvg Data is three columns, an identifier number, a class (2 or 4, based on whether a patient's cancerous cells were benign or malignant), and a 'cluster' result where I devleoped a k-means algorithm to see if I could train a model to predict the right class. This was pulled from a different database, this is just where I'm at now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `np.where` is a `tuple` containing `n` arrays, where `n` is the number of dimensions in your array. The good new is that each of these `n` arrays has the same length (each representing one "index" for every found item), so you could just use the length of any of them:

```
>>> len(data[0])  # or len(data[i]) where i < dimensions of your df7
```

as already mentioned in the comments. However if you just want to know how many items satisfy the condition, you can use `np.count_nonzero`:

```
>>> a = np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([3,3,3,3])

>>> np.count_nonzero(a != b)
3
```

Comment: The first example, `len(data[0])` was the ticket. Now to find out why my k-means algorithm is giving me a 4% error rate half the time and 95% the other half lol

Comment: Assuming you rounded the values 4% and 95% could add up to 100% (well rounding introduces +/- 1 so it's possible). That doesn't sound like a coincidence. Please re-check your formulas for possible errors. :)

Comment: I've looked it over about 4 times now, still can't figure it out. No clue why it does work some of the time and doesn't others when nothing is changing. Whether right or wrong, you would assume it would do the same thing each time. Very Strange, indeed.

Comment: @NickBohl You can ask a new question assuming you can provide some minimal data to reproduce the issue.